# How to use minimp3 with alto in Rust?

Tags: audio, rust, mp3, alto

Is there an example how to use minimp3 with alto in Rust? I tried with a very basic setup, but alto's doc isn't really helpful:

```
[dependencies]
minimp3 = "*"
alto = "*"
```

```rust
use minimp3::{Decoder, Frame, Error};
use alto::{Alto, Stereo};

use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    println!("Playback test");
    let mut decoder = Decoder::new(File::open("damien.mp3").unwrap());
    let alto = Alto::load_default().expect("shit");

    for s in alto.enumerate_outputs() {
        println!("Found device: {}", s.to_str().expect("shit"));
    }

    let device = alto.open(None).expect("can't no open"); // Opens the default audio device
    let context = device.new_context(None).expect("cant create no contexto"); // Creates a default context

    // Configure listener
    context.set_position([1.0, 4.0, 5.0]);
    context.set_velocity([2.5, 0.0, 0.0]);
    context.set_orientation(([0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]));

    let source = context.new_static_source().expect("busshit");

    loop {
        match decoder.next_frame() {
            Ok(Frame { data, sample_rate, channels, .. }) => {
                context.new_buffer::<Stereo<i16>, [i16]>(data, 44_100);
            },
            Err(Error::Eof) => break,
            Err(e) => panic!("{:?}", e),
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is with line 28, I can't match `data` to the right type:

```
context.new_buffer::<Stereo<i16>, [i16]>(data, 44_100);
```

I can't figure out what `data: B` should be.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change it from:

```
context.new_buffer::<Stereo<i16>, [i16]>(data, 44_100);
```

to

```
context.new_buffer::<Stereo<i16>, _>(data, sample_rate);
```

The type it is looking for is `Vec<i16>` but you can use `_` to let it infer the type.

If you using a StaticSource, you may need to read the whole mp3 file first, THEN create the buffer with `context.new_buffer` after the loop.

Otherwise you can use StreamingSource and queue up the frames with `source.queue_buffer`. Here's a good example that queues up an initial 5 buffers, then replenishes those buffers with new ones once they finish playing: [Example](https://github.com/jpernst/alto/blob/master/examples/sine.rs).